# if condition in GNU CLISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need some help, my code doesn't return the good answer when I enter the values myself in the interpreter. Here is my code:

```
(defun compromis() 
  (flet ((prompt (string)
           (format t "~&~a: " string)
           (read nil 'eof nil)))
    (print "Enter values :")
    (let ((E (prompt "tddv_estime"))
          (W (prompt "tddv_worst"))
          (C (prompt "gisement_courant"))
          (M (prompt "gisement_max"))
          (m (prompt "gisement_min")))
      (if (> E W)
          (if (> C m)
              (print "Decrement")
              (print "Error")))
      (if (< E W)
          (if (< C M)
              (print "Increment")
              (print "Nothing"))))))
```

When I'm supposed to read "Increment" with `E=8`, `W=16`, `C=2`, `Max=8` and `Min=1`, I have `"Nothing"` displayed twice...

Answer (score 2):

You see `"Nothing"` twice because
[`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) both *prints* and
*returns* its argument, and, since it is the last form in your function
`compromis`, it returns the value returned by `print`.
Since you are evaluating the code in the REPL (Read-Eval-*Print* Loop),
you see the printout *and* the return value.

PS. Please note that lispers read code by *indentation*, not by paren counting. I edited your function to comply with the common coding standards (actually, Emacs did it for me).

Comment: Okay, i will take this good Lisper habit then, thanks for the indentation :). Is it possible to return only the printout and not the return value ? Maybe i don't see the difference between both terms ?

Comment: If you want to avoid printing the return value, you can use `values`: `(progn (print 1) (values))` will print `1` and return nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I found with your code, during compilation:

```
; caught ERROR:
;   The variable M occurs more than once in the LET.
```

It's because Common Lisp is (in general) case insensitive - reader converts all symbols to upper case, so when code is read `m` becomes `M`. You can create lower case symbols (using for example `|m|` syntax), but it's not very common.

When you rename `M` and `m` to for example `Mx` and `mi` - code works as expected, prints `Increment`.

Comment: Nitpick: Common Lisp **is** case sensitive, **but** the reader converts all symbols to upper case by default. This can be changed, and you can write `|m|` to avoid upcasing.

Comment: @coredump That's what I like about lisp related questions and community, there is no *"good enough"* :) Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, i tried for this situation, it works ! Thank you ! :)